# What's the meaning of "just about as ... as"?

Tags: meaning

Could you please explain it to me what the meaning of the phrase is in general and what's the meaning in this case:

> Mary taught nursing at the school, which Dad said was **just about as** brainwashed **as** a person could get, to be working for the Medical Establishment and the Government both.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "as X as a Y" is a common idiomatic expression to compare two things, often figuratively.

> He is **as tall as a tree**!

One option is to compare this to a figurative *maximum*, to mean *extremely* something:

> She is as smart as **anything**  (she is extremely smart)
>
> He's about as rich as **a person can get**.  (he is extremely rich)

Adding "just about" to this phrase *emphasizes* the comparison

> She is **just about** as smart as a person can get.

In the context of your example, "just about as brainwashed as a person can get" means *"extremely brainwashed"*.  The father believes that being a teaching nurse, and subject to the control of both the "Medical Establishment" and  "the Government", makes Mary *extremely brainwashed*.

Note there is not enough context in this one sentence for us to know how the narrator feels about the father's opinion -- but we can assume more information will follow.